# "Schema is not configured for mutations." problem

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Having Problem.

I keep on getting the error "Schema is not configured for mutations."
I am using graphql and graphql.js
My schema is

```
type User{
  username: String!
  password: String!
  email: String!
  bio: String
  followers: [User]
}
type Query {
  get_user: User
}
input add_user {
  username: String!
  password: String!
  email: String!
  bio: String
}
```

and my query was

```
mutation add_user($user: add_user!) {
 createReview(user: $user) {
  username
  password
  email
  bio

 }

}
```

and my query variables were

```
{

"user": {
  "username":"MrTestData",
  "password":"InsecurePassword127",
  "email": "Fake@FEP.FSD",
  "bio":"I am the best fake test data"

}

}
```

Comment: `createReview` isn't anywhere in the schema you posted.

Comment: How do I add that to the schema? Sorry, I'm new to graphql.

Comment: Also separately, is the name of your mutation really meant to be `createReview`, or should it be `createUser`?

Answer (score 1):

Your schema also needs

```
type Mutation {
  createReview(user: add_user!): User!
}
```

to declare that `createReview` is a mutation that is available.